# How many spanning trees we can build using 26 different nodes that have at least 8 nodes whose degree is exactly 4?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

> What's the number of spanning trees we can build using 26 **different** nodes that have **at least** 8 nodes whose degree is **exactly** 4?

I hope to get well detailed answer if possible.

---

Update: I'm looking for answer and not only hints since it's hard

Comment: What you tried? Any ideas?

Comment: What prevents me from solving this is the fact that I'm looking for tree (In other words connected and no circles) How may I do that?

Comment: There are many options but how may I let that happen for sure

Comment: How many edges does a tree with $26$ vertices have?

Comment: The number of trees for 26 nodes is 26^24 @saulspatz

Comment: That is not what I asked.  Look at my answer.

Comment: The use of the phrase "spanning tree" lends some confusion to your Question.  A graph can be a "tree" in and of itself, but the phrase "spanning tree" ordinarily refers to a subgraph of a (finite, simple) graph $G$ which is a tree and contains all the vertices of $G$.  Hence this subgraph may be said to "span" $G$.  It is a routine exercise to show $G$ contains at least one spanning tree if and only if $G$ is connected.

Answer (score 1):

I will get you started.  I'm not sure how elaborate a full solution would be.

A tree with $26$ vertices has $25$ edges, so the sum of the vertex degrees is $50$.  If $8$ vertices have degree $4$, the sum of the vertex degrees of the remaining $18$ vertices is $18$, so the tree must have $18$ leaves.

Call a vertex with $i$ leaves as neighbors a vertex of type $i$, for $i=0,1,2,3$. (Obviously, there can't be any that have $4$ leaves as neighbors.)  Say there are $n_i$ vertices of type $i$ for $i=0,1,2,3$. Then we have,
$$\begin{align}
n_0+n_1+n_2+n_3&=8\\
n_1+2n_2+3n_3&=18
\end{align}$$
So one approach is to find the solutions to these equations in non-negative integers, and see what graphs can be constructed.

Here is one example.  We have the solution $$n_=2,n_1=0,n_2=0,n_3=6$$  A type  $0$ cannot be adjacent to four type $3$ nodes, because there would be no way to add further nodes to the tree.  Therefore the type $0$ nodes are adjacent, and each must be adjacent to $3$ type $3$ nodes, so there is only one tree with these parameters.

It's your turn now.

Comment: I don't understand what came after "Call a vertex..." why the neighbors are helpful at all for solution...

Comment: Plus the question says at least 8... what you wrote is right for exactly 8

Comment: @Daniel98 Try drawing a picture.  As to your second point, what happens if there are $9$ vertices of degree $4$?  Or to put it another way, we know that there are at least $8$ vertices of degree $4$.  If we consider any $8$ of them, we find that all the others must be of degree $1$.

Comment: The tree will have maximum 18 leaves. not exactly 18

Comment: at the sum of the rest of the degrees is maximum 18

Comment: @Daniel98 That is incorrect.  Try giving an example where that holds.

Comment: How is that incorrect, If the tree has 26 nodes this means it has 25 edges then the total sum of degrees is 50. If at least 18 have a degree of 4 then the degree for the rest is maximum 18 which means we have maximum 18 leaves

Comment: Plus, I don't see how the written above will help solve the problem... (After understating it)

Comment: You are just firing off comments without taking time to think about the answer.  If you think about it, you ought to see how it shows you how to do the problem.  If you don't think it will help you, I'm sorry, but there's nothing I can do about that.